# Create nested dictionary based on structure (skeleton) from one dict and corresponding values from another dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I am having a dictionary as `dict1` which is having the skeleton (the order and nested depth) of the new dictionary I desire. For example:

```
dict1 = {
   "Personnel": {
      "Performance": ""
   },
   "Gaming": {
      "Status": "",
      "Bug Status": ""
   },
   "Compatible": {
      "Minimum": "",
      "Integrity": "",
      "Scaling": ""
   },
   "Comparison": {
      "Difference": {
         "DirectX": ""
      },
      "Vendor": {
         "Intel": "",
         "Xiaomi": ""
      }
   }
}
```

And I am having another dictionary as `dict2` which is having the values corresponding to keys in above `dict1` dictionary along with some additional key value pairs as:

```
dict2 = {
   "Personnel": {
      "Performance": "10.5",
      "Maximum": "50.5"
   },
   "Gaming": {
      "Status": "Cool",
      "Bug Status": "None",
      "Green Status": "Black"
   },
   "Compatible": {
      "Minimum": "5",
      "Integrity": "Yes",
      "Scaling": "No"
   },
   "Comparison": {
      "Difference": {
         "DirectX": "50",
         "Android": "70"
      },
      "Vendor": {
         "Xiaomi": "40"
      }
   },
   "Another property": {
      "Testinfo": "TestTest",
      "Important": {
         "Wow": "MuchDoge"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to create a new dictionary having the skeleton from `dict1` and corresponding value of keys fetched from `dict2`.

Note: I'd want to skip key:value pairs that are not the part of `dict1`. For example: I do not need `'Green Status': 'Black'` in my new dictionary.

Below is the code I tried:

```
def update(dict1 : dict, dict2: dict):  
    new_data = {}
    for k, v in dict1.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = update(v, dict(dict2.keys()))
        if v not in dict2.keys():
            new_data[k] = v
    return new_data
```

but I'm totally missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a *nested dictionary comprehension* to achieve this. Iterate on `dict1.items()` to get the typle of `(key, value)` pairs. Again iterate on `value` dict from previous operation to fetch the keys required for the nested new dict. Then, fetch corresponding value of key from `dict2`. For example:

```
new_dict = {k: {v_k: dict2[k][v_k] for v_k in v_dict} for k, v_dict in dict1.items() }
```

Even better to use `dict.get('some_key')` to handle exceptions if `some_key` key doesn't exists. Hence, above dictionary comprehension expression will become:

```
new_dict = {k: {v_k: dict2.get(k, {}).get(v_k) for v_k in v_dict} for k, v_dict in dict1.items() }
```

This will store `None` as value if any key from `dict1` is not present in `dict2`.

For your sample data, above code will return `new_dict` as:

```
{
   "Compatible": {
      "Scaling": "No",
      "Minimum": "5",
      "Integrity": "Yes"
   },
   "Personnel": {
      "Performance": "10.5"
   },
   "Gaming": {
      "Status": "Cool",
      "Bug Status": "None"
   },
   "Comparison": {
      "Difference": {
         "Android": "70",
         "DirectX": "50"
      },
      "Vendor": {
         "Xiaomi": "40"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with `zip`:

```
from pprint import pprint
dict1 = {'Personnel':
     {'Performance': ''},
 'Gaming':
     {'Status': '',
      'Bug Status': ''},
 'Compatible':
     {'Minimum': '',
      'Integrity': '',
      'Scaling': ''},
 'Comparison':
     {'Difference':
          {'DirectX': ''},
      'Vendor':
          {'Intel': '',
           'Xiaomi': ''}
      }
 }

dict2 = {'Personnel':
         {'Performance': '10.5',
          'Maximum': '50.5'},
     'Gaming':
         {'Status': 'Cool',
          'Bug Status': 'None',
          'Green Status': 'Black',
          },
     'Compatible':
         {'Minimum': '5',
          'Integrity': 'Yes',
          'Scaling': 'No'},
     'Comparison':
         {'Difference':
              {'DirectX': '50',
               'Android': '70'},
          'Vendor':
              { 'Xiaomi': '40'}

          },
     'Another property':
         {
             'Testinfo': 'TestTest',
             'Important': {
                 'Wow': 'MuchDoge'
             }
         }
     }

def update(h, j):
   return {a:d if (a == c and not isinstance(b, dict)) or not isinstance(b, dict) or not isinstance(d, dict) else update(b.items(), d.items()) for (a, b), (c, d) in zip(h, j)}

pprint(update(dict1.items(), dict2.items()))
```

Output:

```
{'Comparison': {'Difference': 'TestTest', 'Vendor': {'Intel': 
'MuchDoge'}},
'Compatible': {'Integrity': 'Yes', 'Minimum': '5', 'Scaling': 'No'},
'Gaming': {'Bug Status': {'Xiaomi': '40'},
           'Status': {'Android': '70', 'DirectX': '50'}},
'Personnel': {'Performance': '10.5'}}
```